# 404 error : unable to call a basic method of a very simple rest web service

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, jboss-eap-7

I try to implement at home a simple rest web service in order to learn this technology.

I use the latest version of JBoss EAP : the 7.
I have created under Java 8 a Maven project.
The deployment is ok but when i want to call a method of my REST Web Service, i have a 404 error.

I follow what to do on specifications and tutorial.

1) I create a WAR whose name is **bddsorties**
In the pom, i have :

```
**<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>sortiesbdd</warName>
            </configuration>
</plugin>**
```

2) I have a class that extends the javax.ws.rs.core.Application class : 
public class App extends Application.
This class is annotated :
**@ApplicationPath("/messorties")**

```
@ApplicationPath("/messorties")
public class App extends Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println( "Just the Main Class Here!" );
    }
}
```

3) I have another class, **my Web Service** annotated with @Path :
**@Path("accueil")**

4) **In this Web Service class** called HelloWorld, there is a **basic method** that i want to call **annotated with** **@Path("helloworld")**

```
@Path("accueil")
public class HelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Path("helloworld")
    public Response getHelloWorld() {
        String value = "Hello World Thomas in REST World";
        return Response.status(200).entity(value).build();
    }
}
```

When i want to call this method by typing http://localhost:8080/sortiesbdd/messorties/accueil/helloworld,
i have a 404 error :
Error HTTP 404

What is wrong in my code ?
i am looking for 2 days, and i can't find a solution.
For me, all seem to be ok, but, there is a mistake that i can't find.

Thank you in advance,
  Thomas

PS: As i read on JBoss documentation, i have a web.xml file, but empty.

Answer (score 1):

Expose your resource classes via App like below:

```
@ApplicationPath("/messorties")
public class App extends Application{

private final Set<Class<?>> classes;

public App(){

 classes = new HashSet<>();
    // add Resources
    classes.add(HelloWorld.class);
}

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return classes;
}

}
```

Also declare your all `@path` annotations like @path("/accueil")

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your @Path annotations like this instead:
@Path("/accueil") and @Path("/helloworld")

Comment: Thanks Duran. I add the antislash but the error remains. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

leave the war file name from the path: http://localhost:8080/messorties/accueil/helloworld

**edit #1:**

I just checked one of my projects I deploy on Wildfly: do you have a webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file?

I have the context root defined there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
  <context-root>/sortiebdd</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

check if you have this configuration defining the context root.

**edit #2:**

besides the jboss-web.xml I have a beans.xml in the WEB-INF directory with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

I have no web.xml, because with the beans.xml and the bean-discovery-mode set to annotated, the web.xml is not needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks Peter to consider my problem. I remove the war file name. I have 404 error too.

Comment: @ThomasLabege: I just added to my answer, hope that helps

Comment: OK Peter. Thanks a lot. I have not such a file. I will create.

Comment: Peter, i have add such a file. But the problem persists. I think that you have put me on the right way, the good way : thanks to you, i gues s now that it's a configuration problem and not a coding problem.Just a remark : the web.xml and jboss-web.xml are Under WebContent/WEB-INF/ directory.

Comment: I have it in my maven project under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF, that depends how your maven project is configured. In the end it must end up in the WEB-INF directory of your war file, so check that. Might be that it is not packed into the war.

Comment: Peter, you are absolutely right : i have not my web.xml and jboss-web.xml files in my war, in the WEB-INF directory. I just add these 2 files manually, and try again. I have always the error. I will see carefully the configuration files.

Comment: check my edit with the info about beans.xml; it might be that the web.xml you have conflicts